# Compute accuracy of program?

Tags: arithmetic

Is there a tool to compute the accuracy of a function in a program? Perhaps a static tool or some debugger-based tool that logs each time an arithmetic operator is applied? So one can avoid quirks in floating-point arithmetic, like destructive cancellation and similar.

Comment: Of interest: [Numerical Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function and you want to monitor its (forward or backward) error, and you have a second function which is capable of measuring that error (say, for $f(x)=\mathrm{sqrt}(x)$, you could define $\mathrm{err}_f(x)=\left|f(x)^2-x\right|$), then of course you can just add that error calculation into your function and have it store its results somewhere. But:

- Many "interesting" functions can't be inverted; and for those that can, it may be no easier to precisely evaluate that inverse. More broadly, implementing an error metric is often just as hard as implementing the function itself, and imprecision in the error metric is indistinguishable from imprecision in the original function.
- Measuring the error based on values passed in during testing may miss specific inputs which cause poor behavior. It's not always trivial to guess what those problematic inputs would be. Yet exhaustively exercising a function could be impractical, because of the huge possible range of inputs.

However, there are strategies which allow you to measure the potential imprecision of a computation for a given input, as long as your function sticks to simple numerical computation. The most common one is [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic), where the output of an operation is a range within which the true value is known to lie. While not a panacaea, interval arithmetic is easy to apply and is a good initial strategy for empirical analysis. There are interval arithmetic libraries available for many languages; see, for example, [Boost's interval arithmetic library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/interval.htm) for C++ and [PyInterval](https://github.com/taschini/pyinterval) for Python.

Comment: Okay. Perhaps one would need to write a custom compiler to get the kind of analytical expressions I was hoping for.

Comment: @Emil There are static analysis tools of that sort, but they're of limited expressive power, and tend to be wildly pessimistic in their conclusions. For nontrivial procedures it's just not possible to mechanically derive exact symbolic error bounds.